# No overload for method 'Next' takes 2 arguments

Tags: javascript

I'm making a js plugin using dotnet syntax via javscript platform.

What I want to achieve: Generate a random number like [C# syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

It looks like this:

```js
(function (global) {
    'use strict';

    //require('babel-polyfill');

    //let Int32 = require('./Int32'),
    //    ArgumentOutOfRangeException = require('./ArgumentOutOfRangeException');

    let Int32 = function () { };
    let ArgumentOutOfRangeException = function () { };

    let Random = (function () {
        let __data = {};

        __data.Next = function (...args) {
            switch (args.length) {
                case 0:
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Int32.MaxValue);
                case 1:
                    (function () {
                        let maxValue = args[0];

                        if (maxValue >= 0) {
                            return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue);
                        }

                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(`'maxValue' must be greater than or equal to 0.`, 'maxValue');
                    }());
                case 2:
                    (function () {
                        let minValue = args[0];

                        let maxValue = args[1];

                        if (minValue <= maxValue) {
                            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue);
                        }

                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(`'minValue' cannot be greater than maxValue.`, `minValue`);
                    }());
                default:
                    throw `No overload for method 'Next' takes ${args.length} arguments`;
            }
        };

        class Random {
            constructor() {
                //
            }
            set Next(value) {
                return __data.Next;
            }
            get Next() {
                return (...args) => __data.Next.call(this, ...args);
            }
            GetType() {
                return 'System.Random';
            }
        }
        return Random;
    }());

    //module.exports = Random;
    global.Random = Random;
}(window));

let random = new Random();
let i = random.Next(100, 500);

console.log(i);
```

It throw this error message:

> Uncaught No overload for method 'Next' takes 2 arguments

My question is: why didn't it caught that case?

```
case 2:
    (function () {
        let minValue = args[0];

        let maxValue = args[1];

        if (minValue <= maxValue) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue);
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(`'minValue' cannot be greater than maxValue.`, `minValue`);
    }());
```

The length of the array is exactly `2`, so why am I getting the error?

Thank you!

Comment: Notice, that `retun` in the IIFE returns from that particular function only. You've forgotten `break` statements, see [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Or rather return the return value coming from IIFEs.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks! You mean: it hit the third case, then hitting the default case?

Comment: Yep, that's what happens. The returns are inside of the IIFEs, they are not returning from `case`s, and missing `break`s let the flow go through the switch statement till `default` will be found.